# MySql how to not show blank spaces using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a board where users can write and post things, and in my board_insert.php file, I have

```
$content=preg_replace("/(\r\n || \n\r)/","<br>",$content);
```

in my mysql database, because of all the spaces, the table is very hard to read. 
so I want to replace all the spaces in content column to `<br>`. I put both `\r\n` or `\n\r` because I didnt know which one meant 'space'.

Is there a better way to do this?
maybe not show the content part in mysql at all? 
because it is not necessary for me to see content part in mysql when I can see it on the board_read page...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$content=preg_replace("/\r?\n/","<br>",$content);
```

That said, you may be better of using another method then editing the data,

This is one way http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

using a `<pre></pre>` tag is another less invasive one. and the best is simple

```
<div style="white-space: pre"> content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$content = str_replace(array("\n","\r"), "", nl2br($content));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would insert the data as is into the database, meaning with the `\n` and/or `\r`.  When you display you can use `nl2br()` to display it as HTML.